# Vue prevent event propagation to children conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, dom-events

This is the example of `ColorButtonGroup` Vue component (template only) that serves as group of checkbox/toggle buttons and has limit of max. options selected (in this case 4 colors).

It uses `ToggleButton` component which works as simple toggle selection with styles apply and it's one of common components we have to use in projects.

```
<template>  
  <div
    class="color-button-group"
    :class="[typeClass, variationClass]">
    <ToggleButton
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="index"
      :color="item.color"
      :type="type"
      @click.native="validateClick"
      @change="onChange(item.id)" />
  </div>
</template>
```

I've implemented all logic needed through methods and event handlers and everything works fine but it's also possible to toggle buttons visually after max. selection reached.

Current behavior:

[image: Current behavior]

Desired behavior:

[image: Desired behavior]

How to prevent event propagation to **children** element(s) conditionally?

`stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` as bubbling up and default action prevention were not helpful.

When max. colors selected, level bellow toggle button shouldn't be triggered (disabled state is not allowed for use).

Comment: Is the `pressed` state of each ToggleButton controlled by the component? i.e. is it set in the component's `data`? I would think so because you aren't binding the `pressed` state through a prop.

Comment: Yeah, `ColorButtonGroup` keeps list of selected values and knows everything but it's unable to stop childs to trigger if not possible anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom `ToggleButton` component has to be modified by adding the new prop `toggleable` which is **true** by default and upper `ColorButtonGroup` controls when it will become **false**.

```
<template>  
  <div
    class="color-button-group"
    :class="[typeClass, variationClass]">
    <ToggleButton
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="index"
      :color="item.color"
      :type="type"
      :toggleable="isValidSelection()"
      @change="onChange(item.id)" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        selected: [],
      };
    },
    methods: {
      isValidSelection() {
        if (this.selected.length < this.maxSelect)
          return true;
        return false;
      },
      onChange(item) {
        if (this.isSelected(item)) {
          this.selected = this.selected.filter(val => val !== item);
        } else if (this.isValidSelection()) {
          this.selected.push(item);
        }
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```